# Custom download path by file type Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, download, download-manager

My grandmother uses a windows10 PC to download and view dewing and embroidery designs. The way her work flow goes is:

1. She finds a design she wants on the design library website
2. She downloads the design file (`.pes)`and a `.pdf` that has an instructional guide, both of those go under `C:\Users\Grandma\Downloads`
3. She finds the location where she wants them( an absurdly nested directory, more or less `C:\Users\Grandma\Documents\Sewing\Designs\Webname\`), makes a new directory for the design and moves files from `Downloads` to that special nested directory.

My quest is, if I make a folder under `Webame`, is it possible to configure the computer or browser(Chrome) to automatically put downloaded files from that website to that folder? I already tried doing this looking under the system settings for default downloads and Chrome’s download settings, along with googling, but I have been unable to find an answer so far.

Answer (score 0):

That's not so hard, you can just redirect the downloads folder. Right click C:\Users\Grandma\Download, click Properties. Now go to the Location tab and click move. Now enter C:\Users\Grandma\Documents\Sewing\Designs\Webname in the text box and click OK. Now all downloads will be saved in that directory.